# What does the command "perfmon /sys /comp" do?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, perfmon

I discovered the command `perfmon /sys /comp` and that seems to allow me to launch it in "transparency mode" among other things.

I'm lacking a creative mind right now, but when would this be useful?

What do those switches mean separately?

Are there additional commands for this utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply launches the Performance Monitor [log Compare tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748917.aspx).

The "transparency" mode enables you to open another log file from a similar data set, and have the windows open over a non transparent window, so you can compare the graphs